# How to know are there any ajax calls are in inprocess in a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing regression testing on a web page where all actions are simulating automatically using some testing tool.Here I faced one issue is, we can check entire page is loaded are not by using javascript method

```
document.readyState === "complete"
```

But it will not validate for a partial page loading which is happening by ajax requests/responses.Is there any way to find any ajax calls are still being processed in a page.

My main motto is, I would like to wait for until page is loaded completely including ajax requests and responses and proceed actions after completion of it.

Comment: In jQuery you can hook into the global Ajax events beforeSend and ajaxComplete https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check:

```
jQuery.active == 0
```

if jQuery.active == 1 -> jQuery is doing stuff, jQuery.active == 0 -> doing nothing